# How can i get access to static method through variable?

Tags: php, oop, variables, static-classes

Trying to get

```
$class = 'MyClass';
$class::classname() - MyClass not found
```

So, is it possible? Or are there other options?

```
public function actionMultiUpdate($module)
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['multiedit']) && count($_REQUEST['multiedit'])) {
        foreach ($_REQUEST['multiedit'] as $id => $data) {
            $model = $module::findOne($id);
            $model->weight = $data['weight'];
            $model->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I work this Yii2 and try to do this, shown above

Comment: Try looking at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: Also this as well: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: Take a look at this as well: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php) to run a static method with the string class name. For example:

```
class Myclass
{

    public static function classname() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

$class = 'MyClass';
echo call_user_func([$class, 'classname']);
```

Also if you want to pass variables into a static method you should pass them in the second parameter. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function doSomething($value1, $value2)
    {
        return $value1 . ' and ' . $value2;
    }
}

$class = 'MyClass';
echo call_user_func([$class, 'doSomething'], 'first value', 'second value');
```

Comment: How can i pass variable into method?

Comment: I think it works, but in yii2 isn't. Maybe you know solution in this framework?

Comment: @EvgenyMusonov Can you attach your code which you try to run to the answer?

Comment: you can see it in the topic

Comment: I don't see code with using call_user_func in the question and I don't know what data is used

Comment: `public function actionMultiUpdate($module)
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['multiedit']) && count($_REQUEST['multiedit'])) {
        foreach ($_REQUEST['multiedit'] as $id => $data) {
            $model = call_user_func([$class, 'findOne'], $id);
     //$model = MainMenu::findOne($id);
     $model->weight = $data['weight'];
     $model->save();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @EvgenyMusono it looks right. so what an error do you get?

Comment: PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'MainMenu' not found

Comment: @EvgenyMusonov your $module variable must contain full name of the class with namespace.

Answer (score -1):

You can put the class name in a variable and call it with the method, or put the class name and method into a variable and then call it. It is also possible to use call_user_func ().

```
class Myclass{
  public static function myMethod(){
    return "return from Myclass::myMethod";
  }
}

//only class name in a variable
$curClass = 'Myclass';
echo $curClass::myMethod();

//class and Method in a variable
$classAndmethod = 'Myclass::myMethod';
echo $classAndmethod();
```

tested with php 7.2.21.